# How to overwrite overloaded variable

Tags: go

i'm experimenting with go with pi calculating formulas, and made this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func bbpformula() {

    var result float64

    for k := 0.0; k <= 100; k++ {

            result += (1 / math.Pow(16.0, k) * ((4 / (8*k + 1)) - (2 / (8*k + 4)) - (1 / (8*k + 5)) - (1 / (8*k + 6))))

    }

    fmt.Println(result)

}

func main() {

    bbpformula()

}
```

and the output is:

3.141592653589793

However, i would like more digits, i tried using the math/big package to make the variables big.Float with simpler formulas, but the arithmetic operations were extremely confusing and slow.

So my idea is overwriting the result variable when its overloaded (maximum capacity), but i have no ideia how to do that!

Could someone please explain to me how that is done?

edit: tried to use the if result > math.MaxFloat64 but the output turns into nothing

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func bbpformula() {

    var result float64
    var resultb float64

    for k := 0.0; k <= 100; k++ {

            result += (1 / math.Pow(16.0, k) * ((4 / (8*k + 1)) - (2 / (8*k + 4)) - (1 / (8*k + 5)) - (1 / (8*k + 6))))
            if result > math.MaxFloat64 {
                    fmt.Println(result)
                    resultb += (1 / math.Pow(16.0, k) * ((4 / (8*k + 1)) - (2 / (8*k + 4)) - (1 / (8*k + 5)) - (1 / (8*k + 6))))
                    if resultb == math.MaxFloat64 {
                            fmt.Println(resultb)
                            result = 0
                    }

            }

    }

}

func main() {

    bbpformula()

}
```

output:

Comment: Does `fmt.Printf("%50.49f", result)` satisfy your use-case? see https://play.golang.org/p/4wxpHcRUDCl

Comment: It helped to have more digits, but i kind of wanted the amount that i wanted, like 200 digits or more.

Comment: You cannot "overlaod" such stuff. Use math.big. Anything else is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MaxFloat32` or `MaxFloat64` in the `math` package. Like, check if `result > math.MaxFloat64`?

Comment: when i try to do this the output turns into nothing, see the edit